# Google+ activities new data collection

Tags: google-plus

Using google+ API APIkey. I am fetching data about public activities.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query="great"&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

To collect new data time greater than the last collected data.
i tried using this url.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=%22great%22&published%3E2014-10-16T07:03:52.221Z&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

But it is not considering published parameter. please suggest me helpful links to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) does not support a `published` parameter. The best you can do is use `orderBy=recent` and discard posts you have already seen.